# what is the correct way of installing Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, google-api, google-calendar-api

Using PowerShell v7.3.1, I am trying to install the Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 library, but I get this error.

[image]

As suggested I run Get-PackageSource

[image]

I have also installed .NET Framework 4.8.1

[image]

I have also tried Install-Module PowerShellGet -Force, which successfully installed the module, but then when I try Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 I get the same error.

what is the correct way of installing Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 using PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 is a Google package. Which is hosted on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3)

You don't appear to have NuGet set as a package source See: [register-packagesource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/register-packagesource?view=powershell-7.3#examples)

```
register-PackageSource -Name MyNuGet -Location https://www.nuget.org/api/v2 -ProviderName NuGet
```